# Parallel bzip2 decompression scan may fail?

Tags: compression, file-format, bzip2

Bzip2 byte stream compression in parallel can be easily done with a FIFO queue where every chunk is processed as parallel task and streamed into a file.

The other way round parallel decompression is not so easy, because everything is bit-aligned and the exact bit-length of a block is known after it's decompressed.

As far as I can see, parallel decompress implementations use magic numbers for block start and stream end and [perform a bit-scan](https://github.com/kjn/lbzip2/blob/master/src/parse.c). Isn't there a small chance that one of the streams contain such a magic value by coincidence?

Possible block validations:

- 4 Bytes CRC
- 6 Bytes "compressed magic"
- 6 Bytes "end of stream magic"
- some bit combinations for the huffman trees are not allowed
- max. x Bytes of huffman stream (range to search for next magic)

Per file:

- 4 Bytes File CRC
- padding at the end

I could implement such a scan by just bit-shifting from the stream until I have a magic. But then when I read block N and it fails, I should (maybe also not) take into account, that it was a false positive. For a parallel implementation I can then stop all tasks for blocks N, N+1, N+2, .. , then try to find the next signature and go one. That makes everything very complicated and I don't know if it's worth the effort? I guess maybe not, but is there a chance that a parallel bzip2 implementation fails?

I'm wondering why a file format uses magic numbers as markers, but doesn't include jump hints. I guess the magic numbers are important for filesystem recovery, but anyway, why can't a block contain e.g 16bits for telling how far to jump to the next block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the source code you linked notes that the magic 48-bit value can show up in compressed data by chance. It also notes the probability, around 10<sup>-14</sup> (actually 2<sup>-48</sup>, closer to 3.55x10<sup>-15</sup>). That probability is at every sample, so on average one will occur in every 32 terabytes of compressed data. That's about one month of run time on one core on my machine. Not all that long. In a production environment, you should assume that it will happen. Because it will.
2. Also as noted in the source you linked, due to the possibility of a false positive, you need to then validate the remainder of the block. You would not stop the subsequent possible block processing, since it is extremely likely that they are all valid blocks. Just validate all and keep the validated ones. Verify when combining that the valid blocks exactly covered the input, with no overlaps. A properly implemented parallel bzip2 decompressor will always work on valid bzip2 streams.
3. It would need to be more than 16 bits, but yes, in principle a block could have contained the offset to the next block, since it already contains a CRC at the start of the block. Julian did consider that in the revision of bzip2, but [decided against it](https://sourceware.org/bzip2/manual/manual.html#limits):

> bzip2-1.0.X, 0.9.5 and 0.9.0 use exactly the same file format as the
> original version, bzip2-0.1. This decision was made in the interests
> of stability. Creating yet another incompatible compressed file format
> would create further confusion and disruption for users.

...

> The compressed file format was never designed to be handled by a
> library, and I have had to jump though some hoops to produce an
> efficient implementation of decompression. It's a bit hairy. Try
> passing decompress.c through the C preprocessor and you'll see what I
> mean. Much of this complexity could have been avoided if the
> compressed size of each block of data was recorded in the data stream.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I'm working on an async parallel bzip2 Rust crate implementation.